# How to check if a function is an homomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

For example:
Let  $$f:\mathbb{Z}_{60} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}$$
$$[x]_{60} \mapsto ([x]_{12} , [x]_{20})$$

1. Prove that it's well defined
2. Check if it's a ring homomorphism and find his kernel

   - How to prove a function is well defined?
   - How should you check if it's an homomorphism in this case?
   - How should you check if it's an homomorphism in general?

Attempt:
I only managed to calculate
$\ker(f) = \{[0]_{60}\}$ and this set contains only that element because $\mathrm{lcm}(12,20) = 60$ , is it right?

Comment: How did the kernel end up being a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$? It should be a subset of the domain. To prove that the function is well-defined, you need to check that the value does not depend on the choice of representative of the congruence class in $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$. To check it is a homomorphism, simply look up the definition and check it (you have the function explicitly given).

Comment: Hint: Something is a ring homomorphism to a direct product $R\times S$, if and only if both components are ring homomorphisms to $R$ respectively to $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $\left[x\right]_{60}=\left[y\right]_{60}$ (same element, represented by different representatives) and then check whether
$\left(\left[x\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[y\right]_{12},\left[y\right]_{20}\right)$.

If that is the case then $f$ is well-defined: the image of $\left[x\right]_{60}$
does not depend on representative $x$.

Check whether $\left[x\right]_{60}.\left[x'\right]_{60}=\left[xx'\right]_{60}$ is send
by $f$ to $\left(\left[x\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\right).\left(\left[x'\right]_{12},\left[x'\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[xx'\right]_{12},\left[xx'\right]_{20}\right)$.

Also do this for addition. $\left[x\right]_{60}+\left[x'\right]_{60}=\left[x+x'\right]_{60}$
should be sent to $\left(\left[x\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\right)+\left(\left[x'\right]_{12},\left[x'\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[x+x'\right]_{12},\left[x+x'\right]_{20}\right)$

Check wether $\left[1\right]_{60}$ is send to $\left(\left[1\right]_{12},\left[1\right]_{20}\right)$.

If  $f$ satisfies these conditions then it is a unitary ringhomomorphism.

You are right about the kernel. Here $f$ is injective.

**addendum**

**Check on welldefined:**

Note here that $\left[x\right]_{60}=\left[y\right]_{60}$ means exactly that $60$ divides $x-y$. This implies that also $12$ and $20$ divide $x-y$. This proves that indeed $\left(\left[x\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[y\right]_{12},\left[y\right]_{20}\right)$ as was to be checked.

**Check on** $f\left(p.q\right)=f\left(p\right).f\left(q\right)$:

$f\left(\left[x\right]_{60}.\left[x'\right]_{60}\right)=f\left(\left[xx'\right]_{60}\right)=\left(\left[xx'\right]_{12},\left[xx'\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[x\right]_{12}\left[x'\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\left[x'\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[x\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\right).\left(\left[x'\right]_{12},\left[x'\right]_{20}\right)=f\left(\left[x\right]_{60}\right).f\left(\left[x'\right]_{60}\right)$

**Check on** $f\left(p+q\right)=f\left(p\right)+f\left(q\right)$:

$f\left(\left[x\right]_{60}+\left[x'\right]_{60}\right)=f\left(\left[x+x'\right]_{60}\right)=\left(\left[x+x'\right]_{12},\left[x+x'\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[x\right]_{12}+\left[x'\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}+\left[x'\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[x\right]_{12},\left[x\right]_{20}\right)+\left(\left[x'\right]_{12},\left[x'\right]_{20}\right)=f\left(\left[x\right]_{60}\right)+f\left(\left[x'\right]_{60}\right)$

Comment: But should I check this for every element in $Z_{60}$?

Comment: There is no need for looking at the elements one by one. That $f$ satisfies these conditions can be proved in a general setting.

Comment: So for the well-definedness part I should (only) check that if $[0]_{60} = [60]_{60}$ then $\left(\left[0\right]_{12},\left[0\right]_{20}\right)=\left(\left[60\right]_{12},\left[60\right]_{20}\right)$? And for the omomorphism-part, $[13]_{60}$ is sent to $([1]_{12},[13]_{20})$ so it should not be an omomorphism. What am I missing?

Comment: For the welldefinedness part see the addition to my edit. I explained there how to do it.

Comment: You have indeed $f\left(\left[13\right]_{60}\right)=\left(\left[1\right]_{12},\left[13\right]_{20}\right)$
but don't forget that $\left[1\right]_{12}=\left[13\right]_{12}$

Comment: So if we had $[x]_{60} \mapsto ([x]_{13} , [x]_{20})$ it would not be well defined. Instead for the homomorphism I should only check that for the element $[1]_{60}$?

Answer (score 0):

For the well-definedness part, this simply says that members of the same equivalence class are mapped to the same value - i.e. prove that the images of x+y*60 (for arbitrary x,y) are mapped to the same equivalence classes by your map.

To check, whether some map $f$ is a homomorphism, you need to check that it fulfills $f(x\circ y)=f(x)*f(y)$, where $\circ,*$ are the connecting operations of the groups/rings/fields or whatever other structure you are using.

In your case, I guess you just want to check the group-homomorphism property of these abelian groups, i.e. you need to check that for x,y arbitrary,
$$f([x]_{60}+[y]_{60})=f([x]_{60})+f([y]_{60})$$
If you have proven well-definedness, you can pick representatives to prove this statement!